# How to check if a string has only one of the specified character?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I know that I can use .contains() to check if a string has a particular character, but I want to check if a string has only one of the character.

For example, if I check for 'a', I want it to return true for "abb" but false for "aabb"

How do I do that?

Comment: For that it's best to use regular' expressions (regex) I think

Comment: You can do something like `string.indexOf(char) == string.lastIndexOf(char)` and account for index not being -1

Comment: @Pawel Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count{}` to do that:

```
ss.count {it == 'a' }
```

It counts the number of `a` in `ss`, to check with `1` , you can just:

```
ss.count {it == 'a' } == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Kotlin` we can solve as below:

```
var ss : CharSequence  = "abdaaa"
val isValid =  ss.filter { item -> item.equals('a', false) }.length == 1
```